# Is it possible to have a clear/seethrough label in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have an image background in my tkinter window and it turns out when you create a label or frame the default is not clear it's grey (it only looks clear as the default background is the same grey).

I initially had the same problem with frames but I placed the background in front of the frames so they were hidden. However, I can't do that with the labels because they contain text that I want to see.

So, is it possible to make the grey not show up/ set the label to "clear" (tried bg="clear" and bg="none")?

Comment: I don't think so. `tkinter` has only very limited transparency support. See [Transparent colors Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104991/transparent-colors-tkinter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have a clear background in the tkinter `label` widget. However, there are ways to get the same output. For simple colour backgrounds, you can match the colour in the background of the label. For picture backgrounds like this example, you can use a canvas but the picture has to be within the same canvas.

Here is how you can use `Canvas`:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
win.config(bg="red")

canvas = tk.Canvas(win, width=200, height=20)
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,30,30, fill="orange")
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_text(10,10, text="This isn't ideal but it works", anchor="nw")

win.mainloop()
```

[image: Example Window]

As you can see, the text doesn't have any background to it and any items beneath it are visible. However, this only applies to items in the canvas. As shown, the window background is red but the canvas background is the default grey - the canvas itself has a background colour but only to widgets outside of the canvas.